# Can't enter c++ code on Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017

I am creating a Windows console application using visual studio 2017, but the console only accepts c code. I am trying to enter:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World";
}
```

It gives some errors like saying "cout" doesn't exist, "std" doesn't contain "cout" and many others. However if I change the code to:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

int main()
{
    printf("Hello World");
}
```

It works fine. How do I make it accept c++ code?

Comment: What file suffix? VS may decide between C and C++ by file suffix. For C++, please, use e.g. `.cpp` or `.cc`. Additionally, you can force the language in the properties of file.

Comment: Concerning VS file properties: Unfortunately, I cannot tell you the property name (it's in German in my VS). The corresponding command line options are: `/TP` for C++ vs. `/TC` for C.

Comment: when you create the project make sure you have checked the "Empty project" and not checked "use precompiled headers". Then make sure the file extension is `cpp` and not `c`.